# Riddle of the Living Game

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> A ring of grills
> A burning bird
> First of my kind
> In simple world

**What am I?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are:

> the [period](https://conwaylife.com/wiki/Period)-2 [oscillator](https://conwaylife.com/wiki/Oscillator) from [Conway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Horton_Conway)'s [Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life), known as '**[Phoenix 1](https://conwaylife.com/wiki/Phoenix_1)**':
>
>  [image: Phoenix 1, from Conway's Game of Life]
>
>  This is an arrangement within mathematician John Conway's famous cellular automaton (see the links above for more details) that infinitely flickers between two states.

*A ring of grills*

> The structure of Phoenix 1 is a *ring* of components which bear a similarity to the '*griddle*' induction coil, making its behaviour dependent on a similar mechanism.

*A burning bird*

> Its name is derived from the [mythical bird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_(mythology)) which is constantly reborn from its own ashes.

*First of my kind*

> Phoenix 1 (as its name might suggest!) was the very *first* 'phoenix' pattern to be discovered in Conway's Game of Life. In the context of the automaton, a 'phoenix' is a pattern all of whose cells die in every generation but that never dies out as a whole - effectively being constantly 'reborn from its own ashes' like the mythological bird.

*In simple world*

> The 'simple world' is Conway's cellular automaton, the Game of Life. In fact, within the title of this puzzle '*The Living Game*' is a vaguely shrouded reference to the *Game of Life*.